# Remote Desktop Connection error

Tags: firewall, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2003-r2

When I try to connect to remote host with **Windows Server 2003 R2 SE** via RDP from another few Windows Server 2003 clients I get the following error.

```
The client could not connect to the remote computer.    
Remote connections might not be enabled or the computer might be too busy 
to accept new connections. It is also possible that network problems
are preventing your connection.
Please try connecting again later. 
If the problem continues to occur, contact your administrator.
```

At the same time server is accessible via RDP from most of the internal machines.
I've already checked **RDP-Tcp** settings and set the network adapter I want to use.
Firewalls are disabled on problem machine and other clients as well.

Remote Desktop is enabled and appropriate permissions are given to the users who are allowed to access server.

I've tried to connect via FQDN, netbios name, IP-address - still the same issue. This excludes possible name-resolution issues.

Any ideas\suggestions highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic network, routing, or hardware firewall issue. Maybe a silly question, but can you contact this server from the "problem" server in any way? For example, ICMP, file shares, remote registry, WMI? That would rule out routing, but leave the rest. Can you install NetMon/Wireshark on the unreachable server? That would show whether or not the packets are arriving.

Comment: Hej, looks like you are right about classic network issue. Ordered port-openings for RDP and now it works!